# Good (better) substition for setInterval or setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

I've got a masterpage with some nice UI (jQuery) features. One of these options is interefering with my embedded YouTube (or other alike-) objects. On each, in this case, setInterval event the embedded video stops displaying new frames (for like a second).

*More detail:*
I've got a "polaroid" gallery (in the header) with only 5 100x100 images in it (test: preloading has no effect on performance) and my gallery will show or hide them (fade-in / fade-out) after a period of time. (test: non-animated display:hide or display:block has no effect on performance).

After some testing and I've come to the conclusion that it isn't the "animated" showing or hiding of the pictures, but it's the interval itself (- since altering to display:hide or block had the same result). Perhaps it is my "gallery" "function" on itself ...

```
 function poladroid() {
     if (!galleryHasFocus) {
         if (galleryMax >= 0) {
             galleryCurrent++;

             if (galleryCurrent > galleryMax) {
                 galleryCurrent = 0;
                 showPictures = !showPictures;
             }
             if (showPictures) {
                 $('#pic-' + galleryCurrent.toString()).show("slow");
             }
             else {
                 $('#pic-' + galleryCurrent.toString()).hide("slow");
             }
         }
     }
     if (!intervalSet) {
         window.setInterval("poladroid()", 3000);
         intervalSet = true;
     }
 }
```

It's not like my function is doing really awkward stuff is it? So, I was thinking I needed a more "loose" interval function.. but is there an option for it?

Ow.. almost forgot to mention it: FireFox and Chrome perform pretty good; using IE (what else) has the most performance problems.

Comment: jScript != Javascript. Mind your tags. Apart from that, if you have a test site up and running, that would be good to get an impression what could be wrong.

Comment: Edited post: forgot to mention is a primary IE-based problem.

Comment: In the future do this OUTSIDE the function
------: 
var tId="";
if (tId=="") tId=setInterval("poladroid()", 3000);

then you can clear it with clearInterval(tId); too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no substitute for setInterval/setTimeout - these *are* the only ways of timing events in browser based ECMAScript.

Its not easy to grasp the *real* issue here, but I'm guessing the whatever you are triggering using setInterval is heavier than it has to be (as it is jQuery) - you should try to make this more efficient.

If you want an easy to use slideshow, take a look at http://github.com/oyvindkinsey/JsSlideshow - it has a demo [here](http://kinsey.no/projects/jsslideshow/)

By the way, do not use a literal as the first argument to setTimeout/setInterval, use a function reference

```
setInterval(poladroid, 3000);
```

Comment: It's not an actual slideshow, it's just stack "polaroid" foto's into the header.
Anyway we've tested this script without the use of jQuery, just plain {object}.style.display = "hidden" and the results were alike - don't think it's jQuery's footprint in this case.

Comment: Since my original question was about replacing the setInterval/Timeout I've accepted this answer as the correct one. Decided I don't actually care that IE users get crappy results - it's just a browser based problem.